# php split a file into $key=>$value pairs with duplicate keys

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying to wrap my head around this and I'm just brain frozen.

I have a file with multiple lines, each line is delimited by "=" into separate pieces of data:

```
// Example file. Syntax: <key>=<Value>
key1=value1
key1=value2
key1=value3
key2=value1
key2=value2
key3=value1
key3=value2
key3=value3
key3=value4
```

I need to explode this file into separate lines, and throw them all in an array such that key1 holds an array of value1, 2, 3, key2 has its values, key3 has its values, so on and so forth. Kind of like this:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
        [0] => value1
        [1] => value2
        [2] => value3
        )
    [key2] => Array
        (
        [0] => value1
        [1] => value2
        )
    [key3] => Array
        (
        [0] => value1
        [1] => value2
        [2] => value3
        [3] => value4
        )
)
```

So far I have the following code:

```
$loadFile = file('file.txt');
$returnArray = array();
foreach ($loadFile as $line) {
  $startWith = substr(trim($line), 0, 2);
    if (empty($line) || $startWith == '//') {
          continue;
  }
  list($key, $value) = explode('=', $line);
  $returnArray[$key] = $value;
}
return $returnArray;
```

However all I'm getting back is:

```
Array ( [key1] => value3 [key2] => value2 [key3] => value4 )
```

I've also tried

```
$loadFile = file('file.txt');
$returnArray = array();
foreach ($loadFile as $line) {
  $startWith = substr(trim($line), 0, 2);
    if (empty($line) || $startWith == '//') {
          continue;
  }
  $exp = explode('=', $line);
  $returnArray[$exp[0]] = $exp[1];
}
return $returnArray;
```

Which also gives me the same result. I've also tried an array_merge which just shoved everything into an array with a numeric value as the key.

Comment: In your first attempt, use `$returnArray[$key][] = $value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is you override the value for your key.

```
$returnArray[$key] = $value;
```

so what yo want is to append your values to a subarray with the `$key` as the parent.

```
$returnArray[$key][] = $value;
```

With the `[]` you append the `$value` to the underlying array.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, just turn them into array syntax for an `ini` file and parse it:

```
$result = parse_ini_string(str_replace('=', '[]=', file_get_contents('file.txt')));
```

More fun, turn them into a query string and parse it:

```
parse_str(str_replace('=', '[]=', implode('&', file('file.txt'))), $result);
```

Both yield:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
            [2] => value3
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
        )

    [key3] => Array
        (
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
            [2] => value3
            [3] => value4
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should  append your values to a subarray 
of  $returnArray[$key]

```
array_push($returnArray[$key],$value) ;
```